# Google firebase deploying issue

Tags: firebase

I've been trying to deploy a firebase project but while deploying I've asked to update my plan from free to paid. Is there any solution for this? BTW this is a mini-trial project for a college event.

While I try to deploy I am getting an error like ,

> Error: Your project multiplayerquiz-afbc5 must be on the Blaze (pay-as-you-go) plan to complete this command. Required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com can't be enabled until the upgrade is complete.

Comment: The solution would be to upgrade the project as the error message says, right?  Are you saying you don't want to upgrade? What is the problem here?

Comment: yeah i don't want to upgrade. Is there any other option?

Comment: My best guess is that your project is using features that require Cloud Functions, which is only available on the Blaze plan. You will either have to not use those features, or upgrade.